Bibundle induced by a morphism of stacks
[This is a repost, because I've written the wrong page number in the previous version of this question. I'm sorry]
I'm currently reading "Orbifolds as stacks" by Eugene Lerman and I'm stuck at a (probably trivial) point.  At page 22, the author describes how to construct the bibundle associated to a stack morphism. Given two Lie groupoid $$G=(G_1\rightrightarrows G_0),\ \ \ \ \ H=(H_1\rightrightarrows H_0)$$ and a stack morphism $F:BG\to BH$, the author states that the $H$-principal bundle $$F(t:G_1\to G_0):P\to G_0$$ has also a left $G$-action induced by the left $G$-action on $G_1$, because $F$ is a functor. It's not clear how this left action is induced by the functoriality of $F$. Could you help me?

Ignoring topology, each element of $G_1$ gives an automorphism of $G_1\to G_0$ (as a right $G$-bundle), and hence by applying $F$ gives an automorphism of $P \to G_0$. This assignment of elements of $G_1$ to automorphisms of $P$ is an action (using functoriality of $F$), so the trick is to show that in fact this is a smooth action.

@DavidRoberts Thank for your answer! Isn't the automorphism of $G_1\to G_0$ only partially defined? Each element $g\in G_1$ can only act on the elements of $G_1$ that have source equal to the target of $g$, right?

Yes, but that's how the action will work in the end anyway. If you have a local section of the source map, then it can act locally on $t\colon G_1\to G_0$ and hence—I believe!—locally on $P$ in a way that's smooth over the domain of the local section. If the local section is defined at a single point, this recovers the setup in my first comment.
